# Problems with Debug Diag trying to get a memory dump

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server, debugdiag

I'm having some problems with an ASP.Net app running on IIS 10 because it's crashing some times giving me a generic WebException with no more data inside it.

I was following this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/09/debug-diagnostic-2-0-creating-a-rule-in-crash-mode/) to get a memory dump with Debug Diag Tool so i can get more insights about what is happening. But after configure the rule and activate it I'm getting 503s from my site, and when I disable the rule everything works again.

Any idea about what could be happening?

Comment: You will have to show us all steps you did to create that crash rule (a sequence of screen shots probably), so that we might know what you did. For WebException, there are more specific articles, like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/09/29/how-to-get-a-dump-for-a-system-net-webexception-using-debugdiag-debug-diagnostics/ The steps slightly vary, but in general Debug Diag is the right tool to use.

Comment: Afair, ASP.NET reports about crashes in Event Log. Did you check it? And yes, describe the configuration of app pools and DebugDiag.